# How to neatly parse arrays of variable length in Amazon Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, text-extraction

In Redshift, I have an event stream table copied a third-party data replicator.  The events are batched by the minute, so that each row in this table represents at least 1 and no more than 1000 events that happened in a given minute.

These batches are represented in arrays of JSON files.  Currently, I'm using [JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) to extract each element of the array.  Problem is, I have to specify each element of the array in the query to extract it; given that there are up to 1000 events in a given JSON, this could result in some very ugly, very long SQL.

Is there a way to do this without manually specifying each element in the array in my query?

Comment: Hey, I solved this exact problem a while back by doing a cross join with a table with numbers 0 to 999 and then using those numbers to index into my array to extract all the values https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT.html. Obviously not all arrays will have length 1000, so after extracting the elements, just select where the extracted value is not null. Probably not the most efficient solution, but it worked for the size of my data.

Comment: Have you considered converting the JSON to normal database columns so that you can take advantage of the full columnar capabilities of Redshift? Extracting from JSON would result in poor database performance.